# Room Database Operation wont crash after callling on main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am using `Coroutines` to perform `db` operations on my `Room` database
I have create a helper for Coroutines as follows

```
object Coroutines {

    fun main(work: suspend(() -> Unit)) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        work()
    }

    fun io(work: suspend(() -> Unit)) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        work()
    }
}
```

Following is the code where i call my insert operation on the main thread

```
class LocalListViewModel(private val localVideoRepository: LocalVideoRepository) : ViewModel() {

     val localVideos = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LocalVideo?>?>()

     fun insertAllLocalVideo() {
          Coroutines.main {
               localVideoRepository.insertLocalVideo(localVideos.value)
          }
     }
}

class LocalVideoRepository(private val db: AppDatabase) {

    suspend fun insertLocalVideo(localVideos: ArrayList<LocalVideo?>?) =
        db.getLocalVideoDao().insertLocalVideos(localVideos)

   }

@Dao
interface LocalVideoDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertLocalVideos(localVideoList: ArrayList<LocalVideo?>?)
}

@Database(entities = [LocalVideo::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getLocalVideoDao(): LocalVideoDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var instance: AppDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            context.getString(R.string.psplayer_db)
        ).build()
    }
}
```

What i don't understand is even after calling on main thread of `Coroutines`, the data gets inserted successfully,instead of crashing?

Comment: Did you opted for [allowMainThreadQueries](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#allowMainThreadQueries()) in RoomDatabase builder?

Comment: @MohammedFarhan No you can see my code in the question.It is the exact code that i have written in my app

Comment: Documentation says `If you need to access the database from the main thread, you should always use async alternatives or manually move the call to a background thread` and coroutine runs asynchronously.

Comment: Calling Coroutines.io in my case runs operation on background thread @MohammedFarhan

Comment: `suspend fun insertLocalVideos(localVideoList: ArrayList<LocalVideo?>?)` -- isn't this a suspending, non-blocking function? If so, why do you expect it to break when called from the main thread? It's _supposed_ to be called like that. However, the way you wrote it will allow any number of concurrent DB operations, including them getting reordered. This is because you `launch` each operation as an independent coroutine.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So is this the right way of using coroutines with Room?

Comment: I can only give you a general coroutines answer: suspending functions, being non-blocking, don't need any special treatment. Call them on any thread that is the most convenient for you. On Android that's the main GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

For an in-depth answer look at the [`CoroutinesRoom.execute`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-master-dev/room/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/room/CoroutinesRoom.kt) helper:

```
    suspend fun <R> execute(
        db: RoomDatabase,
        inTransaction: Boolean,
        callable: Callable<R>
    ): R {
        if (db.isOpen && db.inTransaction()) {
            return callable.call()
        }

        // Use the transaction dispatcher if we are on a transaction coroutine, otherwise
        // use the database dispatchers.
        val context = coroutineContext[TransactionElement]?.transactionDispatcher
            ?: if (inTransaction) db.transactionDispatcher else db.queryDispatcher
        return withContext(context) {
            callable.call()
        }
    }
```

Unless it already is in a transaction it always moves the execution of the actual query onto a IO-optimized dispatcher. So regardless of the calling context a `suspend` room definition will never execute on the application thread.